Alsa Lib Throw Many Error When Start The Script
Error Output:
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.2.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.2.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
Cannot lock down 107350048 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
Cannot lock down 107350048 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Cannot lock down 107350048 byte memory area (Cannot allocate memory)
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.2.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib confmisc.c:1369:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.2.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
ALSA lib conf.c:5180:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib conf.c:5703:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM hdmi
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm.c:2666:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:397:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Cannot open device /dev/dsp
ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:1001:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib confmisc.c:160:(snd_config_get_card) Invalid field card
ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:482:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid card 'card'
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:999:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to open slave
Listening...

When I run this code it should transcribe my speech
Here Is the code:
import speech_recognition as sr

# Create a recognizer object
recognizer = sr.Recognizer()

# Set the microphone source
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    # Optional: Adjust the recognizer's sensitivity to ambient noise
    recognizer.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration=1)

    print("Listening...")

    # Continuously listen and recognize speech
    while True:
        try:
            # Capture audio from the microphone
            audio = recognizer.listen(source)

            # Perform speech recognition (using Google's Web Speech API by default)
            text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)

            # Output the recognized text
            print("You said: ", text)

        except sr.UnknownValueError:
            # This occurs when speech is not understood
            print("Couldn't understand the speech")

        except sr.RequestError as e:
            # This occurs if there's an issue with the speech recognition service
            print("Could not request results; {0}".format(e))


I use card 2 (my usb mic) and I also try my mic in my phone and my main desktop and it work very well.

card 2: UACDemoV10 [UACDemoV1.0], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
Subdevices: 1/1
Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

This Is my /usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf:
#
#  ALSA library configuration file
#

# pre-load the configuration files

@hooks [
    {
        func load
        files [
            "/var/lib/alsa/conf.d"
            "/usr/etc/alsa/conf.d"
            "/etc/alsa/conf.d"
            "/etc/asound.conf|||/usr/etc/asound.conf"
            "~/.asoundrc"
            {
                @func concat
                strings [
                    {
                        @func getenv
                        vars [
                            XDG_CONFIG_HOME
                        ]
                        default "~/.config"
                    }
                    "/alsa/asoundrc"
                ]
            }
        ]
        errors false
    }
]

# load card-specific configuration files (on request)

cards.@hooks [
    {
        func load
        files [
            {
                @func concat
                strings [
                    { @func datadir }
                    "/cards/aliases.conf"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
    {
        func load_for_all_cards
        files [
            {
                @func concat
                strings [
                    { @func datadir }
                    "/cards/"
                    { @func private_string }
                    ".conf"
                ]
            }
            {
                root {
                    @func private_integer
                }
                file {
                    @func concat
                    strings [
                        "/var/lib/alsa/card"
                        { @func private_integer }
                        ".conf.d"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
        table {
            id {
                @func concat
                strings [
                    { @func private_integer }
                ]
            }
            value {
                @func concat
                strings [
                    "cards."
                    { @func private_string }
                ]
            }
        }
        errors false
    }
]

#
# defaults
#

# show all name hints also for definitions without hint {} section
defaults.namehint.showall on
# show just basic name hints
defaults.namehint.basic on
# show extended name hints
defaults.namehint.extended on
#
defaults.ctl.card 2
defaults.pcm.card 2
defaults.pcm.device 0
defaults.pcm.subdevice -1
defaults.pcm.nonblock 1
defaults.pcm.compat 0
defaults.pcm.minperiodtime 5000     # in us
defaults.pcm.ipc_key 5678293
defaults.pcm.ipc_gid audio
defaults.pcm.ipc_perm 0660
defaults.pcm.tstamp_type default
defaults.pcm.dmix.max_periods 0
defaults.pcm.dmix.channels 2
defaults.pcm.dmix.rate 48000
defaults.pcm.dmix.format unchanged
defaults.pcm.dmix.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.dmix.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.dsnoop.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.dsnoop.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.front.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.front.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.rear.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.rear.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.center_lfe.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.center_lfe.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.side.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.side.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround21.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround21.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround40.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround40.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround41.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround41.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround50.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround50.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround51.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround51.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.surround71.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.surround71.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.iec958.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.iec958.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.modem.card defaults.pcm.card
defaults.pcm.modem.device defaults.pcm.device
defaults.pcm.file_format raw
defaults.pcm.file_truncate true     # truncate files via file or tee PCM
defaults.rawmidi.card 0
defaults.rawmidi.device 0
defaults.rawmidi.subdevice -1
defaults.hwdep.card 0
defaults.hwdep.device 0
defaults.timer.class 2
defaults.timer.sclass 0
defaults.timer.card 0
defaults.timer.device 0
defaults.timer.subdevice 0

#
#  PCM interface
#

pcm.hw {
    @args [ CARD DEV SUBDEV ]
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func getenv
            vars [
                ALSA_PCM_CARD
                ALSA_CARD
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.pcm.card
            }
        }
    }
    @args.DEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func igetenv
            vars [
                ALSA_PCM_DEVICE
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.pcm.device
            }
        }
    }
    @args.SUBDEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.pcm.subdevice
        }
    }       
    type hw
    card $CARD
    device $DEV
    subdevice $SUBDEV
    hint {
        show {
            @func refer
            name defaults.namehint.extended
        }
        description "Direct hardware device without any conversions"
    }
}

pcm.plughw {
    @args [ CARD DEV SUBDEV ]
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func getenv
            vars [
                ALSA_PCM_CARD
                ALSA_CARD
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.pcm.card
            }
        }
    }
    @args.DEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func igetenv
            vars [
                ALSA_PCM_DEVICE
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.pcm.device
            }
        }
    }
    @args.SUBDEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.pcm.subdevice
        }
    }       
    type plug
    slave.pcm {
        type hw
        card $CARD
        device $DEV
        subdevice $SUBDEV
    }
    hint {
        show {
            @func refer
            name defaults.namehint.extended
        }
        description "Hardware device with all software conversions"
    }
}

pcm.plug {
    @args [ SLAVE ]
    @args.SLAVE {
        type string
    }
    type plug
    slave.pcm $SLAVE
}

pcm.shm {
    @args [ SOCKET PCM ]
    @args.SOCKET {
        type string
    }
    @args.PCM {
        type string
    }
    type shm
    server $SOCKET
    pcm $PCM
}

pcm.tee {
    @args [ SLAVE FILE FORMAT ]
    @args.SLAVE {
        type string
    }
    @args.FILE {
        type string
    }
    @args.FORMAT {
        type string
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.pcm.file_format
        }
    }
    type file
    slave.pcm $SLAVE
    file $FILE
    format $FORMAT
    truncate {
        @func refer
        name defaults.pcm.file_truncate
    }
}

pcm.file {
    @args [ FILE FORMAT ]
    @args.FILE {
        type string
    }
    @args.FORMAT {
        type string
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.pcm.file_format
        }
    }
    type file
    slave.pcm null
    file $FILE
    format $FORMAT
    truncate {
        @func refer
        name defaults.pcm.file_truncate
    }
}

pcm.null {
    type null
    hint {
        show {
            @func refer
            name defaults.namehint.basic
        }
        description "Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)"
    }
}

# redirect to load-on-demand extended pcm definitions
pcm.cards cards.pcm

pcm.default cards.pcm.default
pcm.sysdefault cards.pcm.default
pcm.front cards.pcm.front
pcm.rear cards.pcm.rear
pcm.center_lfe cards.pcm.center_lfe
pcm.side cards.pcm.side
pcm.surround21 cards.pcm.surround21
pcm.surround40 cards.pcm.surround40
pcm.surround41 cards.pcm.surround41
pcm.surround50 cards.pcm.surround50
pcm.surround51 cards.pcm.surround51
pcm.surround71 cards.pcm.surround71
pcm.iec958 cards.pcm.iec958
pcm.spdif iec958
pcm.hdmi cards.pcm.hdmi
pcm.dmix cards.pcm.dmix
pcm.dsnoop cards.pcm.dsnoop
pcm.modem cards.pcm.modem
pcm.phoneline cards.pcm.phoneline

#
#  Control interface
#
    
ctl.default cards.ctl.default
ctl.sysdefault cards.ctl.default

ctl.hw {
    @args [ CARD ]
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func getenv
            vars [
                ALSA_CTL_CARD
                ALSA_CARD
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.ctl.card
            }
        }
    }
    type hw
    card $CARD
    hint.description "Direct control device"
}

ctl.shm {
    @args [ SOCKET CTL ]
    @args.SOCKET {
        type string
    }
    @args.CTL {
        type string
    }
    type shm
    server $SOCKET
    ctl $CTL
}

#
#  RawMidi interface
#

rawmidi.default {
    type hw
    card {
        @func getenv
        vars [
            ALSA_RAWMIDI_CARD
            ALSA_CARD
        ]
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.rawmidi.card
        }
    }
    device {
        @func igetenv
        vars [
            ALSA_RAWMIDI_DEVICE
        ]
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.rawmidi.device
        }
    }
    hint.description "Default raw MIDI device"
}

rawmidi.hw {
    @args [ CARD DEV SUBDEV ]
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func getenv
            vars [
                ALSA_RAWMIDI_CARD
                ALSA_CARD
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.rawmidi.card
            }
        }
    }
    @args.DEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func igetenv
            vars [
                ALSA_RAWMIDI_DEVICE
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.rawmidi.device
            }
        }
    }
    @args.SUBDEV {
        type integer
        default -1
    }
    type hw
    card $CARD
    device $DEV
    subdevice $SUBDEV
    hint {
        description "Direct rawmidi driver device"
        device $DEV
    }
}

rawmidi.virtual {
    @args [ MERGE ]
    @args.MERGE {
        type string
        default 1
    }
    type virtual
    merge $MERGE
}

#
#  Sequencer interface
#

seq.default {
    type hw
    hint.description "Default sequencer device"
}

seq.hw {
    type hw
}

#
#  HwDep interface
#

hwdep.default {
    type hw
    card {
        @func getenv
        vars [
            ALSA_HWDEP_CARD
            ALSA_CARD
        ]
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.hwdep.card
        }
    }
    device {
        @func igetenv
        vars [
            ALSA_HWDEP_DEVICE
        ]
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.hwdep.device
        }
    }
    hint.description "Default hardware dependent device"
}

hwdep.hw {
    @args [ CARD DEV ]
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func getenv
            vars [
                ALSA_HWDEP_CARD
                ALSA_CARD
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.hwdep.card
            }
        }
    }
    @args.DEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func igetenv
            vars [
                ALSA_HWDEP_DEVICE
            ]
            default {
                @func refer
                name defaults.hwdep.device
            }
        }
    }
    type hw
    card $CARD
    device $DEV
    hint {
        description "Direct hardware dependent device"
        device $DEV
    }
}

#
#  Timer interface
#

timer_query.default {
    type hw
}

timer_query.hw {
    type hw
}

timer.default {
    type hw
    class {
        @func refer
        name defaults.timer.class
    }
    sclass {
        @func refer
        name defaults.timer.sclass
    }
    card {
        @func refer
        name defaults.timer.card
    }
    device {
        @func refer
        name defaults.timer.device
    }
    subdevice {
        @func refer
        name defaults.timer.subdevice
    }
    hint.description "Default timer device"
}

timer.hw {
    @args [ CLASS SCLASS CARD DEV SUBDEV ]
    @args.CLASS {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.timer.class
        }
    }
    @args.SCLASS {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.timer.sclass
        }
    }
    @args.CARD {
        type string
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.timer.card
        }
    }
    @args.DEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.timer.device
        }
    }
    @args.SUBDEV {
        type integer
        default {
            @func refer
            name defaults.timer.subdevice
        }
    }
    type hw
    class $CLASS
    sclass $SCLASS
    card $CARD
    device $DEV
    subdevice $SUBDEV
    hint {
        description "Direct timer device"
        device $DEV
    }
}


And I'm Using Raspberry Pi 5 8GB with
Python: 3.11.2
